# Comparator and PNP transistor circuit methods

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, pnp

I need to build a simple comparator circuit. But afraid of some miscalculation in that design. This circuit will use in SMPS, that's why noise can be injected upon components. I choose R1 considering the comparator sink current and PNP base current. I think, there can be a problem with PNP, it can turn on randomly. Because the comparator has a leakage current flowing inside the output pin, this current can cause the turn of the PNP transistor. Can anybody help me improve that circuit precisely?

[image]

Comment: In your circuit, you already have a resistor that prevents leakage current from turning ON the PNP transistor. This resistor is R2 pull-up resistor. Also, you should consider adding hysteresis to your comparator circuit. A 1M or 680k resistor connected between the Q1 collector and comparator inverting input.

Answer (score 2):

If M1 is switching constantly, then the gate should be actively pulled to ground to turn it off quicker, and you'd need a push-pull driver like below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJRd6X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust R6 for propagation delay symmetry on rising and falling input edge. The adjustment is required on each board, since it depends on M1's threshold voltage. The "nominal" value is about 1k5. R4's value may be reduced if there's cross conduction between Q2 and Q3.

Ideally, Q1, Q2 and Q3 should be surface-mount, and large pads should thermally connect Q1.C-Q2.B and Q1.E-Q3.B.

The input-to-output delay is <200ns:

[image: Input, gate, and output voltages in the circuit above]

The mosfet's gate current is plotted below. The 100 ohm series resistor in the gate would be causing *serious* switching losses. A ferrite bead on the gate lead would be all that's needed.

[image: Gate current waveform]

Comment: This solution is one option, the other is an inverting gate driver IC. According to the original schematic, the MOSFET (5 nF) is turned off only by the 2.3 kΩ resistor, in about 20-30 µs. The question remains, why do we need a 140 A FET for a 1 A load?

Comment: @csabahu That is indeed a question. A gate driver makes life easy, but sometimes they go out of stock, whereas as I always say: if basic discrete BJTs are out of stock, the civilization is gone, so no worries there.